# Can't install bacula caused of an Key-Verification error

Tags: bacula

I do try to install `bacular-dir` on Manjaro, but got the following error while install process:

```
bacula-11.0.5.tar.gz ... Failed (Unknown public Key C0BE2A5FE9DF3643)
```

Fully removing the gpg-keys and re-init the key-rings even don't work like trying to fetch the key manually by:

```
gpg --recv-keys C0BE2A5FE9DF3643
```

How can I get the key installed to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the Webpage of the Maintainer and dowload the latest key:

- https://www.bacula.org/bacula-distribution-verification-public-keys/

Then execute the following command within the directory, where you saved the above key:

```bash
gpg --import Bacula-4096-Distribution-Verification-key.asc
```

After this, the installation should work like expected.